# I am getting the issue: Kernel appears to have died. It will start automatically while running the code, when the execution reaches to model training

Tags: ubuntu, kernel, jupyter

I am running a python code on Ubuntu 20.04 and it ran perfectly fine for 20-30 times. But now the kernel stops working at the training step.
I am using CUDA, cuDNN and tensorflow in the code

It stops working after this line:

```
rfc= RandomForestClassifier(n_estimators=512,max_depth=64, min_samples_split=16, min_samples_leaf=2, max_features=7,n_jobs=-1,class_weight='balanced')
```

I have uninstalled and reinstalled ipykernel and its supporting packages many times but it is of no use. I have also cleared cache of anaconda. But still it is not working

Any leads would be helpful to solve this issue[Error message in command prompt](https://i.stack.imgur.com/anxtK.jpg)